# Clicking AVD "Create Device" button throwing NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-virtual-device

Have seen many posts complaining about AVD Create Device but most complain about the button being disabled. Haven't seen my specific issue addressed anywhere yet.

I'm trying to create a device that will look like my Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini. I'm launching the AVD manager from the command prompt on a 32bit Windows 7 system. In case it matters Eclipse is closed.

[image]

When I click the Create Device button I get this.

```
C:\java\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\tools>android.bat avd

java.lang.NullPointerException at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.widgets.DeviceCreationDialog.okPressed(DeviceCreationDialog.java:916)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.buttonPressed(Dialog.java:472)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:624)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.ui.DeviceManagerPage.onNewDevice(DeviceManagerPage.java:658)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.ui.DeviceManagerPage.access$100(DeviceManagerPage.java:97)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.ui.DeviceManagerPage$3.widgetSelected(DeviceManagerPage.java:215)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.ui.AvdManagerWindowImpl1.open(AvdManagerWindowImpl1.java:146)
at com.android.sdkuilib.repository.AvdManagerWindow.open(AvdManagerWindow.java:94)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.showAvdManagerWindow(Main.java:437)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:379)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:150)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:116)
```

Can anybody help me out? Would really appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, deleting and re installing everything Android related (eclipse, SDK manager and JDK) worked for me, when you uninstall make sure all the files and folders are also deleted.
I would also recommend moving to Android Studio.